# How to revert Status Bar to its default values after using AnnotatedRegion?

Tags: flutter, dart

On initial screens, I am using `AnnotatedRegion` to change color of Status Bar to white.

```dart
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
  value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.white),
  child: ...
)
```

The above code changes status bar color to white but it also affects other screens in the app where I am not using `AnnotatedRegion`, now the status bar of all of them is white so how do I revert it back the default values on those specific screens.

Saw something like below on some other stack overflow answers but they don't work in my case:

```dart
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
```

So how I can bring the status bar back with default behavior, i.e it automatically has a bit of dark color than whatever color the app bar is?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap every screen in `AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>`

If you already has `AppBar` on every screen you should configure it's brightness

AppBar itself wraps content in AnnotatedRegion and sets it's `value: overlayStyle` this way

```
final Brightness brightness = widget.brightness
  ?? appBarTheme.brightness
  ?? theme.primaryColorBrightness;
final SystemUiOverlayStyle overlayStyle = brightness == Brightness.dark
  ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
  : SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark;
```

For first attemp to solve your problem set all your screens AppBar brightness to desired value as in example

Page1:

```
Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(brightness: Brightness.dark))
```

Page2:

```
Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(brightness: Brightness.light))
```

Comment: How to get the 3 different brightness you are using in the above code, i.e `widget.brightness, appBarTheme.birghtness` and `theme.primaryColorBrightness` ?

Comment: As I previously said it's about AppBar and how it counts brightness to use in SystemUiOverlayStyle.

Firstly AppBar tries constructor argument then if it's null it tries get it from appBarTheme and last try is Theme primary color brightness.

If you unfamiliar with Flutter themes read this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

For first attemp to solve your problem set all your screens AppBar brightness to desired value as in example

`Page1 Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(brightness: Brightness.dark))
Page2 Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(brightness: Brightness.light))
`

Comment: Not yet, ran into some other issue with `AnnotatedRegion` which I am trying to understand first as that is required before I can move to this one.